# $T:L^p \to L^p$ , $A$ a dense subset of $L^p$ , $T|_A $ is bounded and has an extension $T'$ . Can we show that $T=T'$ on $L^p$?

Tags: functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, interpolation-theory

> $(a)$ Suppose $T:L^p \to L^p$ is a linear operator(might not be bounded) , $A$ a dense subset of $L^p$ , $T|_A $ is a bounded operator , then $T|_A$ can be extend to all of $L^p$ which we call it $T'$ . Can we show that $T=T'$ on $L^p$ ?
>   $(b)$ If we only assume $T$ is weak $(p,p)$ and sublinear , can we show that $T'=T$

The above question frequently appear when I apply Marcinkiewicz Interpolation theorem , when I show that an operator $T$ is weak $(p,p)$ and weak $(q,q)$ on schwartz space , then $T|_S$ can be extend to $T'$ which is strong $(r,r)$ when $p\lt r \lt q$ . Then I need to show $T'=T$ by using the original definition of the operater $T$ . However , can we only use the property that $T$ is sublinear to show $T=T'$ ?

Comment: Your answer to a is yes if $T$ is bounded: since $T$ is bounded (i.e. continuous), it is completely determined by $T|_A$ for a dense subset $A$ of $L^p$

Comment: I'm not sure what conditions are required to ensure that a weak $(p,p)$ and sublinear map on $L^p$ is continuous.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I have edit the post , we didn't know the boundness of $T$ on $L^p$

Comment: Are we given that $T$ is a closed operator?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom We only know that $T$ is linear or sublinear , and $T$ is bounded on a dense subset of $L^p$ . For example ,T is Hilbert transform .